# How to connect to a Firestore database with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write and read to and from my Firestore database from a Ruby script, eventually from a Rails application.

It seems like a trivial task but when I run a test script inside IRB it won't let me write or read data.

I tried:

- successfully installed `google-cloud-firestore` [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-cloud-firestore)
- downloaded JSON keyfile from within the Firestore console.
- security rules are set to public (read and write)

```
require 'google/cloud/firestore' # => true

# credentials
cred = Google::Cloud::Firestore::Credentials.new('<path/to/my/keyfile/key-projectname-etc.json>') 
# => #<Google::Cloud::Firestore::Credentials:...>

# initialize firestore connection
db = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new(
  project_id: '<MY-PROJECT-ID>',
  credentials: cred
) # => #<Google::Cloud::Firestore::Client:...>

# write a document inside the users collection
db.doc("users/helloFromRuby").set({ name: "yay it worked!"})
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Google::Cloud::UnavailableError (14:failed to connect to all addresses)
```

Comment: Failure to connect doesn't have to be a Ruby problem. Have you checked to see if you have connectivity and it's pingable as it might be a network error.

Comment: Yeah you were right, it was an issue that i had an environmental variable (`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`) that was set, which probably interfered with my keyfile. Anyways deleting this env variable resolved the issue. Thanks for your comment and input.

Comment: Please don't use "EDIT" or "UPDATED" tags in questions or answers. SO already has revision control and we can see what's changed if necessary. Instead add your change where you would have put it if you'd said it originally. Also, since that was the solution, create an answer, writing that as if you were instructing yourself. After a timeout period SO will let you select the answer as the appropriate solution. Congratulations on your first self-answered question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve my issue: I had an environmental variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` initialized that was somehow interfereing with my json keyfile. Deleting that variable solved my issue.