# Connecting Rails Application to Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Would Like to read Data from the Firebase Cloud Firestore. I have already created a project, and added my Rails (6.0.3) application to the fire store db via settings -> add web app. This provided me with script tags containing the firevbase SDK to add to my web application under the body tag, I did all of this.
I am trying to follow the instructions @ https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0#ruby. The very first instruction reads:
'''
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/your/keyfile.json"
'''
I have already downloaded this JSON file by creating a key from the service account associated with my firebase project, this key was downloaded and placed within my project tree. However I do not know where to put Export google creds within my Rails environment? Previously I tried to insert it into environment/development.rb but the export key word is not a part of Ruby syntax.

I have already installed the cloud-firestore-gem and I have been working through this post trying to piece everything together [How to connect to a Firestore database with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101015/how-to-connect-to-a-firestore-database-with-ruby). When I run this within the rails console:

```
cred = Google::Cloud::Firestore::Credentials.new("path/to/myJsonSerivcesKey.Json")
```

I receive this trace back :

```
Signet::AuthorizationError (Authorization failed.  Server message:)
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided."}
```

I think this error has to do with me not doing something correct when using the API key from the service account but I am not really sure. Any advice on how to correct the Invalid OAuth Scope and where to put the export GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS+CREDENTIALS would be great. Also I am not sure why Firebase SDK needs to be pasted into the body tags of the application, could someone explain what this does for the app?

Comment: I think this might be helpful:
https://medium.com/@channaly/connect-to-firebase-realtime-database-from-rails-application-f42c81dbb532
Let me know if it worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but was also using `google-cloud-storage` besides `google-cloud-firestore`.

What fixed it for me was downgrading the cloud-storage gem by changing my gem file to `gem 'google-cloud-storage', '<= 1.21.1'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the scope you want:

```
cred = Google::Cloud::Firestore::Credentials.new "path/to/myJsonSerivcesKey.Json",  scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore"
```

[List of scopes available](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)

Comment: Thank you this worked for me to handle the `Invalid OAuth scope` error. But now I get `GRPC::DeadlineExceeded: 4:Deadline Exceeded`. Any ideas on that one? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I'd suggest opening a separate question for that with a full stack trace and repro.  Could be any number of things since GRPC is used pretty widely through the Google Ruby API.